# Is there an excel function that will let me average a column with a specific title?

Tags: excel, vba

For example, in Sheet 1, I want to average the cells in Sheet 2 that are in the column titled "Hello." Sometimes "Hello" is in column A, sometimes B. The workbook has a code that imports data based on the selected date range, and it doesn't always import the data in the same order. Either way, I want to average column "X" in the same cell in Sheet 1. I thought I could use averageif, but this only works if I am consistently trying to average the same column.

Comment: Use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` to find the column in question.

Comment: Can you get the imported data to be imported as a [table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c#:~:text=To%20quickly%20create%20a%20table,row%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.)? Because then you can just do `=AVERAGE(TableName[Hello])`. If not use [`MATCH`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function) to get the column number and [`INDIRECT`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-indirect-function) to select the column based on the number

Comment: @Dan or just `INDEX` instead of the volatile `INDIRECT`.

Comment: "The workbook has a code that imports data based on the selected date range" - maybe it would be useful to include that here?

Comment: @Dan Thank you!! So I would have to use Match, Indirect, and Average functions in vba to do this?

Comment: @BigBen I will try INDEX

Comment: You don't need to use VBA at all. Those a re worksheet functions. And I really recommend first trying to use a table.

Comment: @Dan, the code that imports the data is quite complicated, and it imports hundreds of rows of data, so I don't want to mess with it. How would I do it without VBA?

Comment: Nevermind, I've got it!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the column headers on Sheet2 start at A1 and cover 3 columns (A to C). You want to find the average of the column with the "Hello" header, so you have to find its position (MATCH), make that a range (INDEX with the row_num argument set to zero to consider the whole column), and finally AVERAGE:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Sheet2!A:C,0,MATCH("Hello",Sheet2!A1:C1,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you!!! However, I am getting the #DIV/0 Error, which doesn't make sense since it's averaging..

Comment: Okay, the problem is that it is only averaging the first cell in the column, which is the title cell

Comment: @guppy this answer works. You should accept it (by clicking green check) as it gives specific instructions that work successfully. Sample file here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gvAmD5yUYp4287c1cw?e=kVXUaP

Answer (score 0):

you can set a named range with

```
dim rn1 as Range
Set rn1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Find("column_name").Offset(1).Resize(n)
```